# MYSQL select query based on another tables entry

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL query that looks like the following

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     invoices_product 
WHERE    FROM_UNIXTIME(unixstamp, '%y%m%d') >= '160701' 
AND      FROM_UNIXTIME(unixstamp, '%y%m%d') <= '160730'
```

The problem I am facing now is that I would like to only get rows for a specific user based on `user_id` which is located in another table called `invoices`, and I would also like to select `zname` from `invoices`.

```
Table invoices (`id`,`user_id`,`zname` etc)

Table invoices_product (`invoice_id`,`unixstamp`,etc)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an `INNER JOIN` between the two tables:

```
SELECT ip.*, i.zname
FROM invoices_product ip
INNER JOIN invoices i
    ON ip.invoice_id = i.id
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(unixstamp, '%y%m%d') >= '160701' AND
      FROM_UNIXTIME(unixstamp, '%y%m%d') <= '160730' AND
      i.user_id = 'some_value'   -- this condition restricts to a given user
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Dont understand the difference between yours and Rahuls query but both work like a charm

Comment: Absolutely! Have to wait 2 minutes before accepted answer though.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a `JOIN` on both tables like

```
SELECT ip.* ,i.zname
FROM invoices_product ip 
JOIN invoices i ON ip.invoice_id = i.id
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(ip.unixstamp, '%y%m%d') >= '160701' 
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(ip.unixstamp, '%y%m%d') <= '160730'
AND i.user_id = 1234;
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Dont understand the difference between yours and Tims query but both work like a charm

Comment: @user3604481, there is none. It's just that Tim has mentioned the join explicitly as `INNER JOIN` which i didn't but it do means an inner join only.